# Dapper MultiMapping for 3 One-To-One relationships

Tags: c#, dapper, multi-mapping

I have 3 tables in Sql Server, one-to-one relationships.

The key is Indice in all 3 tables.

The 3 entities:

```
public class Client
{
     public int Indice { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Surname { get; set; }
     public string Company { get; set; }
     public string Tel1 { get; set; }
     public string Tel2 { get; set; }
}

public class CallClient
{
     public int Indice { get; set; }
     public string CallDateTime { get; set; }
     public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class ResponsePollClient
{
     public int Indice { get; set; }
     public string Question1 { get; set; }
     public string Question2 { get; set; }
     public string Question3 { get; set; }
     public string StatusPoll { get; set; }
}
```

I have this main entity

```
public class DataClient
{
     public Client client { get; set; }
     public CallClient callClient { get; set; }
     public ResponsePollClient pollClient { get; set; }
}
```

The SQL:

> select c.Indice, .... , cc.Indice, ... , pc.Indice, ...
>   from Client c
>   inner join CallClient cc on c.Indice = cc.Indice
>   inner join PollClient pc on c.Indice = pc.Indice

How can I use Dapper for fill the List entity ?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should map your pocos:

```
   var sql = @"SELECT c.Indice 
             , c.Name
             , ....
             , cc.Indice
             , cc.CallDateTime 
             , ....
             , rpc.Indice 
             , rpc.Question1 
             , .... 
        FROM Client c
  INNER JOIN CallClient cc on c.Indice = cc.Indice
  INNER JOIN PollClient pc on c.Indice = pc.Indice";

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            var res = conn.Query<Client, CallClient, ResponsePollClient, DataClient>(sql, (c, cc, pc) =>
            {
                   var d = new DataClient() 
                   {
                     client = c, 
                     callClient = cc, 
                     pollClient = pc
                    };

                return dc;
            }, splitOn: "Indice");
        }
```

Comment: Really `<Client, CallClient, ResponsePollClient, DataClient>`

Comment: `var d = new DataClient() {client = c, callClient = cc, pollClient = pc};
return dc;`

Answer (score 1):

The code should look something like this:

```
var entityList = connection.Query<DataClient, Client, CallClient,ResponsePollClient,DataClient>(
            sql,
            (dataClient, client, callClient, responsePollClient) =>
            {
                dataClient.client = client;
                dataClient.callClient = callClient;
                dataClient.pollClient = responsePollClient;
                return dataClient;
            },
            splitOn: "Indice").ToList();
```

It is pretty straightforward, you can find the complete documentation [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Comment: `splitOn: "Indice,Indice,Indice"` **vs** `splitOn: "Indice"` ?

Comment: A single "Indice" should suffice. https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/a18dc63c688b5173c5dde8b1243b74e26fa262c4/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L1572

Comment: Error: `ArgumentException: When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id`

Comment: Try it by providing all split on columns. "Indice,Indice,Indice"